# Calling Gekko solve gives TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I'm trying to solve an optimal control problem using Gekko. When I try to call `m.solve()`, it gives me `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`, details below. I get this error regardless of my choice of objective function; however, the [only similar issue I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436296/gekko-non-linear-optimization-object-type-error-in-constraint-function-evaluati) had an issue with non-differentiable constraints, and I'm pretty sure my constraints are differentiable. Is there another reason I might get this type of error with Gekko?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-9f7b73717b27> in <module>
      1 from gekko import GEKKO
----> 2 solve_system()

<ipython-input-24-f224d4cff3fc> in solve_system(theta, alpha, rho, chi, L_bar, n, w, delta_inc, xi, phi, tau, kappa, GAMMA, T, SIGMA, BETA, s_init, i_init, r_init)
    257     ##### solve model #####
    258     m.options.IMODE = 6
--> 259     m.solve()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py in solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   1955         # Build the model
   1956         if self._model != 'provided': #no model was provided
-> 1957             self._build_model()
   1958         if timing == True:
   1959             print('build model', time.time() - t)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_write_files.py in _build_model(self)
     54             model += '\t%s' % variable
     55             if not isinstance(variable.VALUE.value, (list,np.ndarray)):
---> 56                 if not (variable.VALUE==None):
     57                     i = 1
     58                     model += ' = %s' % variable.VALUE

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __len__(self)
     23         return self.name
     24     def __len__(self):
---> 25         return len(self.value)
     26     def __getitem__(self,key):
     27         return self.value[key]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __len__(self)
    142 
    143     def __len__(self):
--> 144         return len(self.value)
    145 
    146     def __getitem__(self,key):

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I do call an external (but differentiable) function in my constraints. However, removing it and just doing the work without the function didn't solve the issue. I'd really appreciate any input y'all might be able to offer. Thank you!

Comment: Could you post code that shows the issue? Here are some tips on creating a minimal, reproducible example problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may be because you are using a Numpy array or Python list inside a Gekko expression.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])  # numpy array
y = [2,3,4,5]            # python list

from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
m.Minimize(x)            # error, use Gekko Param or Var
m.Equation(m.sum(x)==5)  # error, use Gekko Param or Var
```

You can avoid this error by switching to a Gekko parameter or variable. Gekko can initialize with a Python list or Numpy array.

```py
xg = m.Param(x)
yg = m.Var(y)

m.Minimize(xg)           
m.Equation(m.sum(yg)==5)
m.solve()
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue - I was using a Numpy array instead of a Gekko variable. Thank you very much!